# any WCF libraries to make it simple?

Tags: c#, wcf

I've got I admit that I'm probably too dumb to fully learn and understand WCF. :(

On the other hand I had learned and used xmpp pretty well ( using MatriX XMPP library ).

So I wanted to ask, maybe there are some other libraries that help passing data from one computer to another to make life simple?

i.e. a library that would open a port/connection and both listen to incoming commands from other computers, as well as be able to send such commands to other computers that are listening to it.

Thanks!

Comment: WCF is about as easy as it gets for IPC, once you understand the basics - you might be better off asking specific questions about what you "don't get"

Comment: @Reed +1 - 100% in agreement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WCF is not a hard technology... there is a learning curve, but ultimately someone who has taken the time to learn how to do it can easily implement the functionality in a couple of minutes.

> i.e. a library that would open a
>   port/connection and both listen to
>   incoming commands from other
>   computers, as well as be able to send
>   such commands to other computers that
>   are listening to it.

Not really.  Most of WCF involves setting up your app.config files so that they work on both ends.  And I doubt there are any libraries that can do that for you.

You simply HAVE to generate and implement a service contract and implement the endpoints/meta data.

MSDN actually has a very decent tutorial. [Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

Even if you DID find a "helper" you should still take the time to learn the technology so that you are prepared to troubleshoot and fix it when it breaks.

And if:

> I've got I admit that I'm probably too
>   dumb to fully learn and understand
>   WCF. :(

were true... you wouldn't be a programmer.

My journey to understanding WCF happened right here on Stackoverflow... you can check it out at : [Cross Application Communication (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070941/cross-application-communication-c).

It might help you understand a little bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind.

1. If you want to use WCF, the check out [ECollective from SOA Collective](http://www.soacollective.com/solutions/ecollective/ecollective-features/). Uses managed mode Discovery to create a config-free WCF client, abstracting all of the things that makes WCF hard like bindings and behaviors.
2. If you want to use something other than WCF, check out [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Try the Idesign Website ... they have a WCF library that you can download and use in your projects.