# Passing of value from one separate application to another

Tags: c#, marshalling, rpc

I'm looking for advice and experiences about proper way to create outputs from one separate application to other independent  application which must take this value for own implementation conditions. to make it clearer in primitive way for example output application writes some undated  value to the text file, and another running application with available path to this file reads it in time loop and if value is found makes some implementation. But I'm trying to find what is more correct way to do the same to pass it from one application directly to another

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best choice for .NET inter-process communication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication)

Comment: You might like to read [interprocess communication protocol that relies heavily on passing windows messages back and forth between applications](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40336286/3796048)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message Queing is certainly what you are looking for.

It will let some applications put messages on the queue and some others (or not actually) consume these messages.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472(v=vs.85).aspx